# Generalizing a unique prime factorisation with specific pattern

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-factorization

By observations, I found that the numbers 11, 101, 1001, 10001, 100001, 1000001, 10000001 and up to 11 digits are all made up of completely unique prime factorisations (square free). E.g. 1001 is equal to 7*11*13, 3 of them are unrepeated prime numbers. Is there a method, possibly using discrete mathematics and concepts of numbers to prove or at least generalize the assumption that 10000...1 is also composed of unique prime factors (a1,a2,...,an) such that they do not equate one another, Or is this assumption unable to be made?

Comment: FYI, a number without repeated prime factors is known as *square-free*, in that it's not divisible by any square number greater than $1$.

Comment: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$10^{11}+1 = 11^2 \cdot 23 \cdot 4093 \cdot 8779$$

Comment: So $10^{11} \equiv -1 \pmod{11^2}$, and therefore $11^2 \mid 10^{11(2n+1)}+1\,$ for all $\,n \in \mathbb{N}\,$.